# Bitwise XOR in Javascript compared to C++

Tags: javascript, c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-xor

I am porting a simple C++ function to Javascript, but it seems I'm running into problems with the way Javascript handles bitwise operators.

**In C++:**

```
AnsiString MyClass::Obfuscate(AnsiString source)
{
    int sourcelength=source.Length();
    for(int i=1;i<=sourcelength;i++)
    {
        source[i] = source[i] ^ 0xFFF;
    }
    return source;
}
```

Obfuscate("test") yields temporary intvalues

```
-117, -102, -116, -117
```

Obfuscate ("test") yields stringvalue

```
‹šŒ‹
```

**In Javascript:**

```
function obfuscate(str) 
{
    var obfuscated= "";
    for (i=0; i<str.length;i++) {

        var a = str.charCodeAt(i);                 
        var b = a ^ 0xFFF;
        obfuscated= obfuscated+String.fromCharCode(b);
    }
    return obfuscated;
}
```

obfuscate("test") yields temporary intvalues

```
3979 , 3994 , 3980 , 3979
```

obfuscate("test") yields stringvalue

```
ྋྚྌྋ
```

Now, I realize that there are a ton of threads where they point out that Javascript treats all numbers as floats, and bitwise operations involve a temporary cast to 32bit int.

It really wouldn't be a problem except for that I'm obfuscating in Javascript and reversing in C++, and the different results don't really match.

How do i tranform the Javascript result into the C++ result? Is there some simple shift available?

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, but you're falling prey to *[The Horror of Implicit Globals](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html)*: You need to declare your `i` variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5HSQ3/)

Judging from the result that xoring `116` with `0xFFF` gives -117, we have to emulate
2's complement 8-bit integers in javascript:

```
function obfuscate(str) 
{
    var bytes = [];
    for (var i=0; i<str.length;i++) {
        bytes.push( ( ( ( str.charCodeAt(i) ^ 0xFFF ) & 0xFF ) ^ 0x80 ) -0x80 );
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

Ok these bytes are interpreted in windows cp 1252 and if they are negative, probably just subtracted from 256.

```
var ascii = [
    0x0000,0x0001,0x0002,0x0003,0x0004,0x0005,0x0006,0x0007,0x0008,0x0009,0x000A,0x000B,0x000C,0x000D,0x000E,0x000F
    ,0x0010,0x0011,0x0012,0x0013,0x0014,0x0015,0x0016,0x0017,0x0018,0x0019,0x001A,0x001B,0x001C,0x001D,0x001E,0x001F
    ,0x0020,0x0021,0x0022,0x0023,0x0024,0x0025,0x0026,0x0027,0x0028,0x0029,0x002A,0x002B,0x002C,0x002D,0x002E,0x002F
    ,0x0030,0x0031,0x0032,0x0033,0x0034,0x0035,0x0036,0x0037,0x0038,0x0039,0x003A,0x003B,0x003C,0x003D,0x003E,0x003F
    ,0x0040,0x0041,0x0042,0x0043,0x0044,0x0045,0x0046,0x0047,0x0048,0x0049,0x004A,0x004B,0x004C,0x004D,0x004E,0x004F
    ,0x0050,0x0051,0x0052,0x0053,0x0054,0x0055,0x0056,0x0057,0x0058,0x0059,0x005A,0x005B,0x005C,0x005D,0x005E,0x005F
    ,0x0060,0x0061,0x0062,0x0063,0x0064,0x0065,0x0066,0x0067,0x0068,0x0069,0x006A,0x006B,0x006C,0x006D,0x006E,0x006F
    ,0x0070,0x0071,0x0072,0x0073,0x0074,0x0075,0x0076,0x0077,0x0078,0x0079,0x007A,0x007B,0x007C,0x007D,0x007E,0x007F
];

var cp1252 = ascii.concat([
    0x20AC,0xFFFD,0x201A,0x0192,0x201E,0x2026,0x2020,0x2021,0x02C6,0x2030,0x0160,0x2039,0x0152,0xFFFD,0x017D,0xFFFD
    ,0xFFFD,0x2018,0x2019,0x201C,0x201D,0x2022,0x2013,0x2014,0x02DC,0x2122,0x0161,0x203A,0x0153,0xFFFD,0x017E,0x0178
    ,0x00A0,0x00A1,0x00A2,0x00A3,0x00A4,0x00A5,0x00A6,0x00A7,0x00A8,0x00A9,0x00AA,0x00AB,0x00AC,0x00AD,0x00AE,0x00AF
    ,0x00B0,0x00B1,0x00B2,0x00B3,0x00B4,0x00B5,0x00B6,0x00B7,0x00B8,0x00B9,0x00BA,0x00BB,0x00BC,0x00BD,0x00BE,0x00BF
    ,0x00C0,0x00C1,0x00C2,0x00C3,0x00C4,0x00C5,0x00C6,0x00C7,0x00C8,0x00C9,0x00CA,0x00CB,0x00CC,0x00CD,0x00CE,0x00CF
    ,0x00D0,0x00D1,0x00D2,0x00D3,0x00D4,0x00D5,0x00D6,0x00D7,0x00D8,0x00D9,0x00DA,0x00DB,0x00DC,0x00DD,0x00DE,0x00DF
    ,0x00E0,0x00E1,0x00E2,0x00E3,0x00E4,0x00E5,0x00E6,0x00E7,0x00E8,0x00E9,0x00EA,0x00EB,0x00EC,0x00ED,0x00EE,0x00EF
    ,0x00F0,0x00F1,0x00F2,0x00F3,0x00F4,0x00F5,0x00F6,0x00F7,0x00F8,0x00F9,0x00FA,0x00FB,0x00FC,0x00FD,0x00FE,0x00FF
]);

function toStringCp1252(bytes){
    var byte, codePoint, codePoints = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < bytes.length; ++i ) {
        byte = bytes[i];
        if( byte < 0 ) {
            byte = 256 + byte;
        }
        codePoint = cp1252[byte];
        codePoints.push( codePoint );

    }

    return String.fromCharCode.apply( String, codePoints );
}
```

Result

```
toStringCp1252(obfuscate("test"))
//"‹šŒ‹"
```

Comment: While this is a correct and usable answer, I wonder how I can expand this, for several XOR operations. See [this jfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5HSQ3/6/)

Comment: @petrobrush Does this give expected results? http://jsfiddle.net/5HSQ3/8/, it results in undefined CP1252 characters, which my Cp1252 function replaces with the `0xFFFD` (�) unicode replacement character. I'd need to see the original results for this to know what to do with the unusde CP1252 characters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP-1252 for the grey boxes

Comment: @petrobrush here's the same jsfiddle that logs intermediate byte results for multiple xor operations http://jsfiddle.net/5HSQ3/9/

Comment: @petrobrush basically what I'm doing is the same C operations, after which I turn the result into 2's complement signed 8-bit integer. I should have made that an intermediate step.

Comment: I've modified http://jsfiddle.net/5HSQ3/11/  according to this: *According to the information on Microsoft's and the Unicode Consortium's websites, positions 81, 8D, 8F, 90, and 9D are unused, however the Windows API MultiByteToWideChar maps these to the corresponding C1 control codes.* They are now control characters according to that and thus won't be visible in a string

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `AnsiString` is in some form, an array of `char`s. And this is the problem. in [c](/questions/tagged/c), `char` can typically only hold 8-bits. So when you XOR with `0xfff`, and store the result in a `char`, it is the same as XORing with `0xff`.

This is not the case with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript). JavaScript using Unicode. This is demonstrated by looking at the integer values:

`-117 == 0x8b` and `3979 == 0xf8b`

I would recommend XORing with `0xff` as this will work in both languages. Or you can switch your [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) code to use Unicode.

Comment: It seems like an old C++ Builder class library with some custom AnsiString/WideString classes. It's definitely about the size of char, I'm just not sure how much bits are there and I don't have an access to C++ Builder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `AnsiString` contains 8-bit characters (since the ANSI character set is 8 bits). When you assign the result of the XOR back to the string, it is truncated to 8 bits, and so the resulting value is in the range [-128...127].

(On some platforms, it could be [0..255], and on others the range could be wider, since it's not specified whether `char` is signed or unsigned, or whether it's 8 bits or larger).

Javascript strings contain unicode characters, which can hold a much wider range of values, the result is not truncated to 8 bits. The result of the XOR will have a range of at least 12 bits, [0...4095], hence the large numbers you see there.

Assuming the original string contains only 8-bit characters, then changing the operation to `a ^ 0xff` should give the same results in both languages.

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your `AnsiString` to `wchar_t*`. Only then obfuscate its individual characters:

```
AnsiString MyClass::Obfuscate(AnsiString source)
{
   /// allocate string
   int num_wchars = source.WideCharBufSize();
   wchar_t* UnicodeString = new wchar_t[num_wchars];
   source.WideChar(UnicodeString, source.WideCharBufSize());

   /// obfuscate individual characters
   int sourcelength=source.Length();
   for(int i = 0 ; i < num_wchars ; i++)
   {
       UnicodeString[i] = UnicodeString[i] ^ 0xFFF;
   }

   /// create obfuscated AnsiString
   AnsiString result = AnsiString(UnicodeString);

   /// delete tmp string
   delete [] UnicodeString;

   return result;
}
```

Sorry, I'm not an expert on C++ Builder, but my point is simple: in JavaScript you have WCS2 symbols (or UTF-16), so you have to convert `AnsiString` to wide chars first.

Try using `WideString` instead of `AnsiString`

Comment: I doubt this works, because the unicode string will have 12-bit characters which you are stuffing into an array of 8-bit values...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know `AnsiString` at all, but my guess is this relates to the width of its characters. Specifically, I suspect they're less than 32 bits wide, and of course in bitwise operations, the width of what you're operating on matters, particularly when dealing with 2's complement numbers.

In JavaScript, your `"t"` in `"test"` is character code 116, which is b00000000000000000000000001110100. 0xFFF (4095) is b00000000000000000000111111111111, and the result you're getting (3979) is b00000000000000000000111110001011. We can readily see that you're getting the right result for the XOR:

```
116  = 00000000000000000000000001110100
4095 = 00000000000000000000111111111111
3979 = 00000000000000000000111110001011
```

So I'm thinking you're getting some truncation or similar in your C++ code, not least because -117 is b10001011 in eight-bit 2's complement...which is exactly what we see as the last eight bits of 3979 above.